# WCF - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, wcf

Hello I'm trying to consume this WCF service when I received this error on the client side
I searched some solutions online but they where suggesting circular dependency and inability to serialize complex objects which is not the case for me

that's the DataContract I'm trying to send

```
[DataContract]
public class CapitalDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ItemSize { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ItemBranch { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double ItemPrice { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ItemCount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double Capital
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)ItemCount * ItemPrice;
        }
    }

}
```

and that's the service that is trying to send it

```
    public IEnumerable<CapitalDTO> GetCapital(int? BranchId = null)
    {
        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            unitOfWork = scope.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
            var capital = unitOfWork.ItemsInBrranches.GetItemsInBranchesByBranch(BranchId).Select(c => new CapitalDTO
            {
                ItemBranch = c.Branch.Name,
                ItemName = c.Item.Name,
                ItemPrice = c.Item.Price,
                ItemSize = c.Item.Size.Size,
                ItemCount = c.Amount
            });
            return capital;
        }
    }
```

as I'm still considered a WCF newbie I'm not sure where my problem lays and I need some help

**Update:**
only methods that returns objects returns this exception so I'm guessing it might be a serialization problem after all0

Answer (score 0):

At a guess - I suspect that all of properties need public setters so that deserialization can take place on the client side.  As 'Capital' is a calculated property I'd suggest removing this entirely, or adding a 'dummy' Setter to it that you would only the deserializer would call, and would effectively not do anything.

Comment: @C-Knight
well, I tried omitting the capital property but that didn't work either, I don't think it's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Okay apparently the problem is in resolving the unitofwork dependency inside a life scope, it seems that it get's disposed along with the DbContext before WCF service is done with it

```
public IEnumerable<CapitalDTO> GetCapital(int? BranchId = null)
{
        unitOfWork = container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
        var capital = unitOfWork.ItemsInBrranches.GetItemsInBranchesByBranch(BranchId).Select(c => new CapitalDTO
        {
            ItemBranch = c.Branch.Name,
            ItemName = c.Item.Name,
            ItemPrice = c.Item.Price,
            ItemSize = c.Item.Size.Size,
            ItemCount = c.Amount
        });
        return capital;
}
```

one other thing, as C. Knight pointed out I should define a public setter in order for the Capital property to be serialized